# scroll the text inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a controller view, that includes, (image, and text).

the two components are in `UIScrollView`, the image is `UIImageView`, and the text is `UITextView` (scroll is enabled). while i am trying to scroll the whole screen, the text doesn't scroll with it, because it has its own scroll.

what I need is to scroll the text with the whole screen scroller. (Merge the scroll of the text with the scroll of the whole one).

should I change the type of text to label instead of textview or what should I do exactly?

Thank You,

Comment: You should resize the 'UITextView' (make it higher) so that it will fit all the text. Of course you should change 'UIScrollView's 'contentsSize' appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

use this method :

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView==your_textview)
    {
        [yourscroolview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textView.center.y-180) animated:YES];
    }


}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [yourscroolview resignFirstResponder];
    [yourscroolview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: In fact, I don't want to edit the text, just I want to read it, but the text is larger than the size so I need a scroll, and already I have a scroll with UIViewScroll, so I want to merge the scroll of the text with the UIViewScroll. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in you `viewWillAppear:` method if text to `UITextView` are assign at Load time..

```
yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTextView.frame.origin.x, yourTextView.frame.origin.y, yourTextView.frame.size.width, yourTextView.contentSize.height);
yourTextView.text=@"Your Text";
float fscrview = yourTextView.frame.origin.y + yourTextView.frame.size.height + 20;
yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
```

**For Ex.**

```
yourTextView.delegate = self;
yourTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
yourTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
yourTextView.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<br />\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<br />\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<br />\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.";
yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTextView.frame.origin.x, yourTextView.frame.origin.y, yourTextView.frame.size.width, yourTextView.contentSize.height);
float fscrview = yourTextView.frame.origin.y + yourTextView.frame.size.height + 20;
yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
```

Comment: the text is bigger than the text view size, so it needs a scroll right?
I want to when i scroll the whole uiviewscroll, the text also scrolls with the main scroll. 
what you gave me, it works if the text is not too long, but the text is bigger than the size of text view.

Comment: then just set that text size instead of 12.0 in this line txtDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]; and exactly till i am not understand dude what u want exactly bcoz which think u first need , thats fullfill in the above code...

Comment: if you check bbc application, in the detail of the article, they have image and text, when you scroll the text also scrolls,

Comment: exactly i do its wait i also post my app image

Comment: @CarinaM when i scroll the text at that time whole scrollview is scrollup and also Image whichis inside of the scrollview...

Comment: the scroll of the whole scroll view is enabled right?
the user interaction of the text view is disabled, 
I can't scroll the text because the user interaction is disabled

Comment: do I need something else in the storyboard attributes inspector to change ??

Comment: but you seeen whole text dude bcoz we set the frame of UItextView with its contentsize so ur textview displayed with whole texts and with its size our scrollview's frame also set with its whole controls... now got it??

Comment: @CarinaM now i update whole code please copy paste that code just change some variable name which u used and also add that textview in scrollview also use my text and check that you seen whole texts or not...

Comment: ok let me re-check my work, and i will give you a feedback thank you alot